# jQuery $(this).tagName returns "HTML"

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have this jQuery code:

```
    $('*').mouseover(function() 
    {
        $('#log').text($(this)[0].tagName);
    });
```

And In my page, I have a bunch of elements, and a DIV with the id "log". When the user mouses over any of the elements, I want their element name (e.g. `p` or `h2`) to appear in the `#log`. But whenever I mouse over anything, it returns `HTML`. How do I fix this?

Comment: note that `$(this)[0]` is exactly equivalent to `this`, but slower.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
$('*').mouseover(function(evt) 
{
    $('#log').text($(this)[0].tagName);

    evt.stopPropagation();
});
```

Your issue, I think, is that the event gets propagated up the chain until it hits `<html>` and that's where it stops. This should help that.

EDIT: It might also help to narrow the scope, i.e. `$('#container > *')`.

Answer (score 2):

It is because the events are all bubbling up to `html` where they are being handled.

Try this...

```
$(document).mouseover(function(event) {
   $('#log').text(event.target.tagName);
});
```

Now you only attach one event, and let them all bubble up to `document` where they will be handled.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('*').bind('mouseover', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('#log').text($(this)[0].tagName);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your event is bubbling up to the html dom node...  you don't want this.  This will fix it:

```
$('*').mouseover(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  $('#log').text(this.tagName);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the first element of a document is the html tag. So it will get the first hover command. Look up - at least- for the body element.

Answer (score 0):

I created a Fiddle to help you: http://jsfiddle.net/ErickPetru/NQfZh/

As you can see, I suggest you to use `mouseenter` insted, then event propagation will not be a problem. If you use `mouseover`, mouse will be firing this event on each elements and their parents all the time.

Also, `.attr("tagName")` is better because you don't need any `[0]` index.

Answer (score -1):

You're attaching this event handler to **any** DOM element by selecting "*".
Without event.stoppropagation() ... every action is routed down (up!) to html.

try

```
$('*', 'body').mouseover(function() 
{
    $('#log').text($(this)[0].tagName);
});
```

which restricts the tag-detection to elements contained in body.

Comment: this will still bubble up to whatever element is the directly under body.  I think he wants the specific element that you're hovering over, so you need to stop the propagation